# Approximate solutions to non polynomial equations

Tags: equation-solving

Let's assume the following symbolic equations

$$E=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}+\frac{e d_1(p)}{r}+\frac{e^2d_2(p)}{r^2}$$

being $d_{i}$ some generic function of $p$.
I would like to find solutions to this equation in terms of $p$ and for small values of the constant $e$. How can I do this using Mathematica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll make an example of the functions $d_i(p)$:

```
d1[p_] = Sin[p];
d2[p_] = p^2 - 7;
```

Series-expansion of the solution for small $e$: I'll use $E=$`F` because the symbol `E` is already in use. The order of the series-expansion is set to 2 here but can be increased at will,

```
Assuming[F > 0, 
  AsymptoticSolve[F == Sqrt[p^2 + m^2] + (e d1[p])/r + (e^2 d2[p])/r^2,
    {p, Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]}, {e, 0, 2}] // FullSimplify]
```

> {{p -> (1/(
>      4 ((F - m) (F + m))^(3/2)
>        r^2))(-e^2 (m^2 + 4 F (F - m) (F + m) (-7 + F^2 - m^2)) + 
>        4 (F^2 - m^2)^2 r^2 + e^2 m^2 Cos[2 Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]] + 
>        4 e F (-F^2 r + m^2 r + 
>           e F Sqrt[F^2 - m^2] Cos[Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]]) Sin[Sqrt[
>          F^2 - m^2]])}}

This is the solution that, for $e=0$, passes through $p_0=\sqrt{F^2-m^2}$. There is also the other branch that passes through $p_0=-\sqrt{F^2-m^2}$; choose the branch in the [`AsymptoticSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSolve.html) input.

For the more complex problem in the comments, it's sufficient to extend the assumptions a bit:

```
Assuming[ma > 0 && mb > 0 && F > ma + mb, 
  AsymptoticSolve[
    F == Sqrt[p^2 + ma^2] + Sqrt[p^2 + mb^2] + (e d1[p])/r + (e^2 d2[p])/r^2,
    {p, Sqrt[(F - ma - mb) (F + ma - mb) (F - ma + mb) (F + ma + mb)]/(2 F)},
    {e, 0, 2}] // Refine]
```

> (lengthy output)

Comment: Hi Roman, thank you for the answer. I have tried to apply your suggestion to the following Assuming[F > 0, 
  AsymptoticSolve[F == Sqrt[p^2 + ma^2]+Sqrt[p^2+mb^2] + (e d1[p])/r + (e^2 d2[p])/r^2,
    {p, Sol1[p]}, {e, 0, 2}] // FullSimplify], being Sol1[p] the positive root for F==Sqrt[p^2 + ma^2]+Sqrt[p^2+mb^2]. Unfortunately it doesn't solve it, is it normal?

Comment: There is a tipo: Only d1[p] is used in the equation!

Comment: I saw it, indeed I am worried that by using different d1, d2, mathematica just can't make it in solving everything in a reasonable amount of time. Could it be?

Comment: @Andrea.Phys maybe add some more assumptions? I think this should work in principle. Keep in mind that `AsymptoticSolve` is an experimental function and may have unexpected trouble. I'm away from the computer and cannot try, the weather is splendid in Europe!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks, I'll correct it when I get to it.

Answer (score 7):

Just an idea how to solve the problem without specifying `d1[p],d2[p]` (Perturbation theory, `MMA version <12` )

First assume the solution p can be approximated by `p ->  p0 + p1 edr + p2 edr^2 + p3 edr^3 (* edr=e/r *)`

Substituting into the equation and series expansion

```
Clear[d1,d2]
ser = Series[-F + Sqrt[p^2 + m^2] + (edr d1[p]) + (edr^2 d2[p]) /. 
p ->  p0 + p1 edr + p2 edr^2 + p3 edr^3, {edr, 0, 2}] // Normal
(*-F + Sqrt[m^2 + p0^2] + edr ((p0 p1)/Sqrt[m^2 + p0^2] + d1[p0]) +edr^2 ((m^2 p1^2)/(2 (m^2 + p0^2)^(3/2)) + (m^2 p0 p2)/(m^2 + p0^2)^(3/2) + (p0^3 p2)/(m^2 + p0^2)^(3/2) + d1[p0] + p1 Derivative[1][d1][p0])*)
```

The series coefficients can be solved  for `p0,p1,p2`

```
CoefficientList[ser, edr] // FullSimplify[#, F > m > 0] &
Simplify[Solve[% == 0, {p0, p1, p2}], F >m> 0]
(*{{
p0 -> -Sqrt[F^2 - m^2], 
p1 -> (F d1[-Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]])/Sqrt[F^2 - m^2], 
p2 -> (1/(2 (F^2 - m^2)^2))(m^2 Sqrt[F^2 - m^2] d1[-Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]]^2 +2 F (F^2 - m^2)^(3/2) d2[-Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]] +2 F^2 (F^2 - m^2) d1[-Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]]Derivative[1][d1][-Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]])
}, {
p0 -> Sqrt[F^2 - m^2], 
p1 -> -((F d1[Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]])/Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]), 
p2 -> -(1/(2 (F^2 - m^2)^2))(m^2 Sqrt[F^2 - m^2] d1[Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]]^2 +2 F (F^2 - m^2)^(3/2) d2[Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]] +2 F^2 (-F^2 + m^2) d1[Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]] Derivative[1][d1][Sqrt[F^2 - m^2]])
}}*)
```

Comment: That's precisely what `AsymptoticSolve` does in a more automated way.

Comment: Yes, but without predefined functions `d1[p],d2[p]` and for users with MMA versions`<12`